# python update query - no such column

Tags: python

[image]I need little help with my query. I want to update specific value room,name,surname however I'm getting error no such column. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
def editGuest():
    viewGuests()
    print("Choose room number:")
    roomNumber = input()
    print("You chooose", roomNumber)
    try:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT room,name,surname FROM Guest WHERE room = {}".format(roomNumber))
        rowz= cur.fetchone()
        print("ROOM", "\tNAME", "\tSURNAME")
        print(rowz[0],rowz[1],rowz[2])
        print("What would you like to change?")
        print("1 - Room, 2 - Guest Name, 3 - Guest Surname")
        userInput = input()
        if userInput == "1":
            print("Enter new room number")
            newRoom = input()
            cur.execute("UPDATE Guest SET room = {} WHERE room = {}".format(newRoom, roomNumber))
            con.commit()
        elif userInput == "2":
            print("Enter new name")
            newName = input()
            cur.execute("UPDATE Guest SET name = {} WHERE room = {}".format(newName,roomNumber))
            con.commit()
        elif userInput == "3":
            print("Enter new Surname")
            newSurname = input()
            cur.execute("UPDATE Guest SET surname = {} WHERE room = {}".format(newSurname,roomNumber))
            con.commit()
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a python question, but what are the columns of `Guest` table? And which line is actually failing?

Comment: room, name surname only

Comment: So which line is failing?

Comment: Please note that the way you are using format is insecure.  Don't use python's builtin `format` function, but rather use the native SQL formatter that properly escapes symbols that were maybe given from user input:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: Can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` or similar expression?

Comment: I'm trying to make it work first, then I will fix the query. Guest is the table, room, name, surname columns.

Comment: what is the exact error ?

Comment: The error is : no such column .